# Why aren't the drivers for Broadcom preinstalled?

Tags: wireless, networking

As Broadcom wireless adapters are installed in most laptops, It stands to reason that the drivers, firmware etc. should be preinstalled as part of the installation process. I am aware that they are proprietary, but so are other the other items when the option is checked at the beginning of the installation.

Answer (score 1):

Those "other things" aren't included on the CD. They're downloaded. Are you suggesting it downloads a network driver without a network driver? "What good is a phone call... if you're unable to speak?", etc.

But you've essentially answered your own question. They're not included because they're proprietary.

Comment: So are many other things, such as flash installed during a 'clean' installation. I just don't see why some proprietary things are allowed during installation but not something as critical as a wireless connection.

Comment: I think the main thing is it's a network driver. Even if there was an opt-in system for it, it'd need a network connection.

Comment: During installation, the CD/USB is checking the hardware, and an internal wireless adaptor is definitely hardware. As the needed drivers are in the repositories, shouldn't this be a part of the installation? I can do this stuff blindfolded by now, but to be a mainstream OS, this seems to be such a simple thing to include.